# How to fix pipeline deployment. template.json Error: Task failed while parsing with following error: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-synapse, cicd

Our team is trying to set up a CI/CD pipeline to move data from Synapse Dev/Test environment to Synapse Production environment.

Each Synapse Workspace resides in its own Resource Group inside its own Subscription.

The Dev/Test workspace environment is fully built out with datasets, pipelines, linked services, pools, etc. We have exported the template and parameter files from the dev/test workspace in Azure Portal and uploaded to our GitHub repository in our collaboration branch (main).

When deploying the pipeline in Azure DevOps we receive the following error. There seem to be no syntax errors or missing brackets and no changes were made to the file before uploading to GitHub.

```
2023-03-13T22:04:51.8230701Z ##[section]Starting: ARM Template deployment: Subscription scope
2023-03-13T22:04:51.8768523Z ==============================================================================
2023-03-13T22:04:51.8769295Z Task         : ARM template deployment
2023-03-13T22:04:51.8769738Z Description  : Deploy an Azure Resource Manager (ARM) template to all the deployment scopes
2023-03-13T22:04:51.8770069Z Version      : 3.217.1
2023-03-13T22:04:51.8770568Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-03-13T22:04:51.8770987Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment
2023-03-13T22:04:51.8771331Z ==============================================================================
2023-03-13T22:04:53.2342898Z ARM Service Connection deployment scope - Subscription
2023-03-13T22:04:53.2526889Z Creating deployment parameters.
2023-03-13T22:04:53.2564436Z The detected encoding for file 'D:\a\r1\a\PMI-BI-Synapse-Artifacts-Source\templates\template.json' is 'utf-8'
2023-03-13T22:04:53.2601923Z ##[error]Check out the troubleshooting guide to see if your issue is addressed: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
2023-03-13T22:04:53.2623026Z ##[error]Error: Ensure the Template file ( 'D:\a\r1\a\PMI-BI-Synapse-Artifacts-Source\templates\template.json' ) is valid. Task failed while parsing with following error: Unexpected end of JSON input
2023-03-13T22:04:53.2633869Z (node:964) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
2023-03-13T22:04:53.2799021Z ##[section]Finishing: ARM Template deployment: Subscription scope
```

Also, we added the template files to the same repo as the artifacts and just added them to their own folder named templates [image: GitHub Main Folder]

Link to Tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/continuous-integration-delivery#set-up-a-stage-task-for-azure-synapse-artifacts-deployment

We've tried using a JSON Validator and verified that the template.json file is valid. When checking the file with the accompanying parameters.json file in VSCode, we get the following error: `Template validation failed: The value of deployment parameter 'vulnerabilityAssessments_Default_storageContainerPath' is null. Please specify the value or use the parameter reference. See https://aka.ms/arm-deploy/#parameter-file for details.`

Since we don't have VulnerabilityAssessments enabled, we tried removing that dictionary from template.json and parameters.json, but still ran into the same exist task error.

Comment: It's telling you the error. You have a parameter in your ARM template named `vulnerabilityAssessments_Default_storageContainerPath`. You aren't providing a value for it.

Comment: You are amazing!... and that seems like a serious flaw in the **Export Template** feature since we don't have VA enabled. I realized you need to start a new deployment in order to pick up changes made in GitHub, otherwise it uses the last commit from the recent deployment.

To fix, I ended up creating a storage container called **vascans** and setting to default value in template.json. I was still gettng errors that parameters.json was `null` so I filled all parameters in with default values from template.json. I'm now getting another error, but that's for another post. Thanks for your help!